# GitHub for Mac no longer installs Git message

Tags: macos, git, github

I have been using the Github for Mac app and it works great.

This morning while launching the Github app I get the following message:

> **GitHub for Mac no longer installs Git**
>
> OS X 10.9 and later includes Git, so GitHub for Mac will no longer
>   install Git as part of its command line tools.
>
> The version of Git you have installed through GitHub for Mac is no
>   longer supported. It's recommended that you uninstall it as soon as
>   possible.
>
> **[ Uninstall Git Later]**  **[ Uninstall Git Now ]**

Should I uninstall Git? Will I lose my git configs ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can uninstall Git (the one oncluded by GitHub for Mac)

You won't loose any configuration, unless you have been fiddling with `git config --system`.
Only the "system" config would have been modifying the installation folder of that embedded Git.

Comment: @Aurelien, how did this work out for you? I want to hear if you lose any of your configuration before I uninstall.

Comment: Got this message too. No idea how to use command line - this blows my mind from a service that I'm paying for.

Comment: @JaydenLawson for the command line, this could help a bit: http://www.appcoda.com/git-source-control-in-xcode/

Comment: Thank you VonC. Sorry I could not reply earlier. I simply clicked the Uninstall Git Now button and it did some magic. Git still works well and my configs are still there. I will try to push through the app to make sure everything is working.

Comment: Well I lost my command line git tool. I had an older version of github desktop installed, possibly pre - OS X 10.9, which may explain why it happened.